# How can I perform a Unicode aware character by character comparison?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

My application has an international target, people from many countries will use it and they will enter text (text I have to process) using their own language.

If, for example, I have to list differences of two strings using a character by character comparison is this simple C# code enough or I'm missing something?

```
var differences = new List<Tuple<int, char, char>>();
for (int i=0; i < myString1.Length; ++i)
{
    if (myString1[i] != myString2[i])
        differences.Add(new Tuple<int, char, char>(i, myString1[i], myString2[i]));
}
```

Is given code effective to perform this task in different languages (my users aren't *limited* to US characters set)?

Comment: Related: ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @Filburt absolutely: I linked that article in many UNICODE related answers, I should add a link also here!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Could you also add a link to some reference about why this is an acceptable question for SO, and that it's OK to basically just post a massive blog article?

Comment: @musefan directly from [help link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) in the "Ask Question" page. Is it massive? Yes, it is because topic is vast and you see and see again and see again same questions related to same topic (is there a limit for answer length?). Is question too broad? Yes to be an umbrella where users may find links and useful information to solve their problem (without asking again another almost duplicate question).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I am not arguing the ability to answer your own question. I myself have done that a few times (albeit not within a few seconds of posting the question), but the question doesn't meet the standards. So why should it be acceptable?

Comment: [Here is a suggestion that you shouldn't do this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/838807),

Comment: @musefan from your link _"This is not a place to post a blog so make sure that the question/answer is **general enough** to be helpful to other members but not so broad that it doesn't target a specific programming issue_". IMO it targets a specific programming issue (so general we can see many questions almost dupes of this) but this may be time to ask people's opinion on meta! If you're right I'll just delete this.

Comment: oooooo... edit war! (The second paragraph should definitely be removed, it's not part of the actual question)

Comment: You should not be including a bunch of meta information in the question itself.  Your question is there to *ask a question* not tell people how to answer it.

Comment: @Servy I understand that (even if I don't agree). Waiting some more feedback on meta to decide if this has to be deleted or not!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Are you planning on creating a question on Meta for that feedback?

Comment: @musefan I did (Servy comes from meta), I want to understand how _Q&A style_ tool can be used and what its limits are. In my opinion it can be a great tool but I wouldn't misuse it against SO _rules_.

Comment: As the question stands now, I think it's scope is narrow enough. However, that said, I believe your self-answer's intro needs to be greatly shortened by removing information that is no longer relevant to your newly narrowed question.

Comment: @DPenner but if I trim the answer then it'll have no sense. It should be improved, refined, some parts removed but also expanded! I see many questions on SO that are always _around_ this topic and I thought a general very introductory answer may help. If it can't be a good Q&A style post "as is" (see [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278206)) then I prefer to delete it all together. Of course I don't like to see SO as a _quick patch/solve my problem_ site and I'd like to see it as a learning resource (both for who asks and for who answers) but if it's not what most users want...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti All IMHO, while this question is a good fit, the answer doesn't fit the question (eg. I enjoyed reading the Cultural Differences section onwards). The problem I have is that "the asker" and users like myself who had this show up in their feed already know a lot of what you wrote in the Intro. Just your title implies that: a) they are aware of multiple encodings b) they know that Unicode is not as straightforward as might be expected. In summary, your question addresses advanced encoding issues, whereas your answer starts at the very basics, which most readers already know.

Comment: @DPenner you're right, original question was much more _abstract_ (what can I do to be ready for globalization?). I moved "introduction" to the end, even if introductory there are links to other posts I feel lazy to move and incorporate in other paragraphs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Encoding

Unicode defines a list of *characters* (letters, numbers, analphabetic symbols, control codes and others) but their representation (in bytes) is defined as *encoding*. Most common Unicode encodings nowadays are UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32. UTF-16 is what usually is associated with Unicode because it's what has been chosen for Unicode support in Windows, Java, NET environment, C and C++ language (on Windows). Be aware it's not the only one and during your life you'll for sure also meet UTF-8 text (especially from web and on Linux file system) and UTF-32 (outside Windows world). A very introductory must read article: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [UTF-8 Everywhere - Manifesto](http://utf8everywhere.org/). IMO especially second link (regardless your opinion UTF-8 vs UTF-16) is pretty enlightening.

Let me quote Wikipedia:

> Because the most commonly used characters are all in the Basic Multilingual Plane, handling of surrogate pairs is often not thoroughly tested. This leads to persistent bugs and potential security holes, even in popular and well-reviewed application software (e.g. CVE-2008-2938, CVE-2012-2135)

To see where issue is just start with some simple math: Unicode defines around 110K code points (note that not all of them are [grapheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme)). "Unicode character type" in C, C++, C#, VB.NET, Java and many other languages on Windows environment (with notable exception of VBScript on old ASP classic pages) is UTF-16 encoded then it's two bytes (type name here is intuitive but completely misleading because it's a *code unit*, not a character nor a code point).

Please check this distinction because it's fundamental: a code unit is logically different from a Character and, even if sometimes they coincide, they're not same thing. How this affect your programming life? Imagine you have this C# code and your specifications (written by someone who thinks about *true* definition of Character) says "password length must be 4 **characters**":

```
bool IsValidPassword(string text ) {
    return text.Length >= 4;
}
```

That code is **ugly, wrong and broken**. `Length` property returns number of *code units* in `text` string variable and now your know they're different. Your code will validate <kbd>n̊o̅</kbd> as valid password (but it's made by two characters, four code points - which almost always coincide with code units). Now try to imagine this applied to all layers of your application: an UTF-8 encoded database field naïvly validated with previous code (where input is UTF-16), errors will sum and your Polish friend *Świętosław Koźmicki* won't be happy of this. Now think you have to validate user's first name with same technique and your users are Chinese (but don't worry, if you don't care then they will be your users for very short time). Another example: this naïve C# algorithm to count distinct Characters in a string will fail for same reason:

```
myString.Distinct().Count()
```

If user enters this Han character  then your code will wrongly return...2 because its UTF-16 representation is `0xD840 0xDC11` (BTW each of them, alone, is not a valid Unicode character because they're high and low surrogate, respectively). Reasons are explained in greater detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23370462/1207195), a working solution is also provided so I just repeat here essential code:

```
StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(text)
    .AsEnumerable<string>()
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

This is roughly equivalent to `codePointCount()` in Java to count code points in a string. We need `AsEnumerable<T>()` because `GetTextElementEnumerator()` returns `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable`, a simple implementation is described in [Split a string into chunks of the same length](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111925/13424) (remember that to check [Unicode Text Segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/) for all the rules, for example if trying to implement an *ellipsis* algorithm for text trimming).

Is this something only related to string length? Of course not, if you handle **keyboard input** `Char` by `Char` you may need to fix your code. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655918/korean-not-recognized-in-combobox) about Korean characters handled in `KeyUp` event.

Unrelated but IMO helpful to understand, this C code (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652031/1207195)) works on `char` (ASCII/ANSI or UTF-8) but it'll fail if straight converted to use `wchar_t`:

```
wchar_t* pValue = wcsrchr(wcschr(pExpression, L'|'), L':') + 1;
```

Note that in C++ 11 there is a new great set of classes to handle encoding and clearer type aliases: `char8_t` (from C++ 20), `char16_t` and `char32_t` for, respectively, UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 encoded characters. Be aware that you also have `std::u8string`, `std::u16string` and `std::u32string`. Note that even if `length()` (and its `size()` alias) will still return count of code units you can easily perform encoding conversions with `codecvt()` template function and using these types IMO you'll make your code more clear and explicit (isn't astonishing `size()` of `u16string` will return number of `char16_t` *elements*). For more details about Characters counting in C++ check [this nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4579215/1207195). In C things are pretty easier with `char` and UTF-8 encoding: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298149/1207195) IMO is a must-read.

### Culture Differences

Not all Languages are similar, they don't even share some basic concepts. For example our current definition of [grapheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) can be pretty far from our concept of [Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing)). Let me explain with an example: in Korean Hangul alphabet letters are combined into a single [syllable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable) (and both letters and syllables are Characters, just represented in a different way when alone and in a word with other letters). Word <kbd>국</kbd> (*Guk*) is one syllable composed by three letters <kbd>ㄱ</kbd>, <kbd>ㅜ</kbd> and <kbd>ㄱ</kbd> (first and last letter are the same but they're pronounced with different sounds when they're at beginning or end of a word, that's why they're transliterated <kbd>g</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>).

Syllables let us introduce another concept: *precomposed and decomposed sequences*. Hangul syllable *han* <kbd>한</kbd> can be represented as a single character (`U+0D55C`) or a decomposed sequence of letters <kbd>ᄒ</kbd>, <kbd>ᅡ</kbd> and <kbd>ᆫ</kbd>. If you're, for example, reading a text file you may have both (and users may enter both sequences in your input boxes) but they must compared equal. Note that if you type that letters sequentially they'll be displayed always as single syllable (copy & paste single characters - without spaces - and try) but final form (precomposed or decomposed) depends on your IME.

In Czech "ch" is a digraph and it's treated as a single letter. It has it's own rule for collation (it's between <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd>), with Czech sorting *fyzika* comes before *chemie*! If you count Characters and you tell your users that word *Chechtal* is composed by 8 Characters they'll think your software is bugged and your support for their language is merely limited to a bunch of translated resources. Let's add exceptions: in *puchoblík* (and few other words) <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> are not a digraph and they're separated. Note that there are also other cases like "dž" in Slovak and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%BE) where it's counted as single character even if it uses two/three UTF-16 code points! Same happens also in many other languages too (for example *ll* in Catalan). True languages have more exceptions and special cases than PHP!

Note that appearance alone is not always enough for equivalence, for example: <kbd>A</kbd> (`U+0041` LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A) is not equivalent to <kbd>А</kbd> (`U+0410` CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A). Conversely character <kbd>٢</kbd> (`U+0662` ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO) and <kbd>۲</kbd> (`U+06F2` EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO) are visually and conceptually equivalent but they are different Unicode code points (see also next paragraph about numbers and *synonyms*).

Symbols like <kbd>?</kbd> and <kbd>!</kbd> are sometimes used as characters, for example earliest [Haida language](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/haida.htm)). In some languages (like earliest written form of Native Americans languages) also numbers and other symbols have been borrowed from Latin alphabet and used as letters (mind this if you have to handle that languages and you have to strip alphanumeric from symbols, Unicode can't distinguish this), one example *!Kung* in Khoisan African language. In Catalan when *ll* is not a digraph they use a diacritic (or a middot (`+U00B7`)...) to separate characters, like in *cel·les* (in this case character count is 6 and code units/code points are 7 where an hypothetical non-existing word *celles* would result in 5 characters).

Same word may be written using in more than one form. This may be something you have to care about if, for example, you provide a full-text search. For example Chinese word 家 (house) can be transliterated as *Jiā* in *pinyin* and in Japanese same word may be also written with same Kanji 家 or as  いえ in *Hiragana* (and  others too) or transliterated in *romaji* as *ie*. Is this limited to words? No, also characters, for numbers is pretty common: <kbd>2</kbd> (Arabic number in Roman alphabet), <kbd>٢</kbd> (in Arabic and Persian) and <kbd>二</kbd> (Chinese and Japanese) are exactly same cardinal number. Let's add some complexity: in Chinese it's also very common to write the same number as <kbd>兩</kbd> (simplified: <kbd>两</kbd>). I don't even mention prefixes (micro, nano, kilo and so on). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28023468/1207195) for a real world example of this issue. It's not limited to far-east languages only: apostrophe (`U+0027` APOSTROPHE or better (`U+2019` RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) is used often in Czech and Slovak instead of its superimposed counterpart (`U+02BC` MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE): *dʼ* and *d'* are then equivalent (similar to what I said about middot in Catalan).

Maybeyou should properly handle lower case "ss" in German to be compared to <kbd>ß</kbd> (and problems will arise for case insensitive comparison). Similar issue is in Turkish if you have to provide a *non-exact* string matching for <kbd>i</kbd> and its forms (see section about *Case*).

If you're working with *professional* text you  may also meet ligatures; even in English, for example *æsthetics* is 9 code points but 10 characters! Same applies, for example, for *ethel* character œ (`U+0153` LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE, absolutely necessary if you're working with French text); *horse d'ouvre* is equivalent to *horse d'œvre* (but also *ethel* and *œthel*). Both are (together with German *ß*) *lexical* ligatures but you may also meet *typographical* ligatures (such as <kbd>ﬀ</kbd> `U+FB00` LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF) and they have they're own part on Unicode character set (*presentation forms*). Nowadays diacritics are much more common even in English (see tchrist's post about [people freed of the tyranny of the typewriter](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80397/95126), please read carefully Bringhurst's citation). Do you think you (and your users) won't ever type *façade*, *naïve* and *prêt-à-porter* or "classy" *noöne* or *coöperation*?

Here I don't even mention *word counting* because it'll open even more problems: in Korean each word is composed by syllables but in, for example, Chinese and Japanese, Characters are counted as words (unless you want to implement word counting using a dictionary). Now let's take this Chinese sentence: 这是一个示例文本 rougly equivalent to Japanese sentence これは、サンプルのテキストです. How do you count them? Moreover if they're transliterated to *Shì yīgè shìlì wénběn* and *Kore wa, sanpuru no tekisutodesu* then they should  be matched in a text search?

Speaking about Japanese: full width Latin Characters are different from half width Characters and if your input is Japanese *romaji* text you have to handle this otherwise your users will be astonished when <kbd>Ｔ</kbd> won't compare equal to <kbd>T</kbd> (in this case what should be just [glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) became code points). Remember this if you're giving, for example, markdown files to translate because `[name](link)` parsing might be broken because of this.

OK, is this enough to highlight problem **surface**?

### Duplicated Characters

Unicode (primary for ASCII *compatibility* and other historical reasons) has duplicated characters, before you do a comparison you have to perform [normalization](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) otherwise <kbd>à</kbd> (single code point) won't be equal to <kbd>à</kbd> (<kbd>a</kbd> plus `U+0300` COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT). Is this a corner uncommon case? Not really, also take a look to [this real world example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15980310/1207195) from Jon Skeet. Also (see section *Culture Difference*) precomposed and decomposed sequences introduce *duplicates*.

Note that diacritics are not only source of confusion. When user is typing with his keyboard he'll probably enter <kbd>'</kbd> (`U+0027` APOSTROPHE) but it's supposed to match also <kbd>’</kbd> (`U+2019` RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) normally used in typography (same is true for many many Unicode symbols almost equivalent from user point of view but distinct in typography, imagine to write a text search inside digital books).

In short two strings must be considered equal (this is a very important concept!) if they are *canonically equivalent* and they are canonically equivalent if they have the same linguistic meaning and appearance, even if they are composed from different Unicode code points.

### Case

If you have to perform case insensitive comparison then you'll have even more *problems*. I assume you do not perform hobbyist case insensitive comparison using `toupper()` or equivalent unless, one for all, you want to explain to your users why `'i'.ToUpper() != 'I'` for [Turkish language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) (<kbd>I</kbd> is not upper case of <kbd>i</kbd> which is <kbd>İ</kbd>. BTW lower case letter for <kbd>I</kbd> is <kbd>ı</kbd>).

Another problem is *eszett* <kbd>ß</kbd> in German (a ligature for long s + short s used - in ancient times - also in English elevated to dignity of a character). It has an upper case version <kbd>ẞ</kbd> but (at this moment) .NET Framework wrongly returns `"ẞ" != "ß".ToUpper()` (but [its use is mandatory](http://www.stagn.de/Portals/0/101125_TopR5.pdf) in some scenarios, see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23444839/1207195)). Unfortunately not always *ss* becomes *ẞ* (upper case), not always *ss* is equal to *ß* (lower case) and also *sz* sometimes is *ẞ* in upper case. Confusing, right?

### Even More

Globalization is not only about text: what about dates and calendars, number formatting and parsing, colors and layout. A book won't be enough to describe all things you should care about but what I would highlight here is that few localized strings won't make your application ready for an international market.

Even just about text more *questions* arise: how this applies to regex? How spaces should be handled? Is an *em space* equal to an *en space*? In a *professional* application how "U.S.A." should be compared with "USA" (in a free-text search)? On the same line of thinking: how to manage diacritics in comparison?

How to handle text storage? Forget you can safely *detect* encoding, to open a file you need to know its encoding. Of course unless you're planning to do like HTML parsers with `<meta charset="UTF-8">` or XML/XHTML `encoding="UTF-8"` in `<?xml>`).

### Historical "Introduction"

What we see as text on our monitors is just a chunk of bytes in computer memory. By convention each value (or group of values, like an `int32_t` represents a number) represents a *character*. How that character is then drawn on screen is delegated to something else (to simplify little bit think about a *font*).

If we arbitrary decide that each character is represented with one byte then we have available 256 symbols (as when we use `int8_t`, `System.SByte` or `java.lang.Byte` for a number we have a numeric range  of 256 values). What we need now to so decide each value which character it represents, an example of this is [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (limited to 7 bits, 128 values) with *custom* [extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) to also use upper 128 values.

[That's done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), habemus *character encoding* for 256 symbols (including letters, numbers, analphabetic characters and control codes). Yes each ASCII extension is proprietary but things are clear and easy to manage. Text processing is so common that we just need to add a proper data type in our favorite languages (`char` in C, note that formally it's not an alias for `unsigned char` or `signed char` but a [distinct type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24059593/1207195); `char` in Pascal; `character` in FORTRAN and so on) and few library functions to manage that.

Unfortunately it's not so easy. ASCII is limited to a very basic character set and it includes only latin characters used in USA (that's why its preferred name should be usASCII). It's so limited that even [English words with diacritical marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_terms_with_diacritical_marks) aren't supported (if this made the change in modern language or vice-versa is [another story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-19-869126-2)). You'll see it also has other problems (for example its wrong sorting order with the problems of [ordinal and alphabetic comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950845/1207195)).

How to deal with that? Introduce a new concept: *code pages*. Keep a fixed set of basic characters (ASCII) and add another 128 characters specific for each language. Value 0x81 will represent Cyrillic character <kbd>Б</kbd> (in DOS code page 866) and Greek character <kbd>Ϊ</kbd> (in DOS code page 869).

Now serious problems arise: 1) you cannot mix in the same text file different alphabets. 2) To properly *understand* a text you have to also know with which code page it's expressed. Where? There is not a standard method for that and you'll have to handle this asking user or with a reasonable guess (?!). Even nowadays [ZIP file "format" is limited to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997517/1207195) for file names (you may use UTF-8 - see later - but it's not standard - because there is not a standard ZIP format). In [this post a Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9974970/1207195) working solution. 3) Even code pages are not standard and each environment has different sets (even [DOS code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:DOS_code_pages) and [Windows code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Windows_code_pages) are different) and also names vary. 4) 255 characters are still too few for, for example, Chinese or Japanese language then more complicated encodings have been introduced ([Shift JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS), for example).

Situation was terrible at that time (~ 1985) and a standard was absolutely needed. [ISO/IEC 8859](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) arrived and it, at least, solved point 3 in previous problem list. Point 1, 2 and 4 were still unsolved and a solution was needed (especially if your target is not just raw text but also *special* typography characters). This standard (after many revisions) is still with us nowadays (and it somehow coincides with Windows-1252 code page) but probably you won't ever use it unless you're working with some legacy system.

Standard which emerged to save us from this chaos is world wide known: **Unicode**. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode):

> Unicode is a computing industry standard for the consistent encoding, representation and handling of text expressed in most of the world's writing systems. [...] the latest version of Unicode contains a repertoire of more than 110,000 characters covering 100 scripts and multiple symbol sets.

Languages, libraries, Operating Systems have been updated to support Unicode. Now we have all characters we need, a shared well-known code for each, and the past is just a nightmare. Replace `char` with `wchar_t` (and accept to live with `wcout`, `wstring` and friends), just use `System.Char` or `java.lang.Character` and live happy. Right?

**NO. It's never so easy**. Unicode mission is about *"...encoding, representation and handling of text..."*, it doesn't *translate* and adapt different cultures into an abstract code (and it's impossible to do it unless you kill the beauty in the variety of all our languages). Moreover encoding itself introduces some (not so obvious?!) things we have to care about.

Comment: "UTF-16 is what usually is associated with Unicode" Only if you are on Windows (and you can never be sure they are really using unicode there, due to earlier UCS-2 and that all is BMP problem). And it is certainly **not** the C and C++ wide encoding (outside windows, that's UTF-32). Also, since when does C# `string` deal in codepoints instead of UTF-16 codeunits?

Comment: @Deduplicator yes this post is pretty limited to Windows world (and cross platform environment .NET and Java). It's complex enough even without C and C++ cross-platform compatibility. On Windows, unless you're using Windows NT 4, it's always UTF-16 (starting with Win2K so it's a pretty safe assumption). You're right about codepoint vs codeunit, fixed where I saw it and where appropriate, tnx!

Comment: Good, *now* I can vote on it all.

Comment: To @DOWNVOTERS: as you should know votes to answer and to question are unrelated (even if they're both written by same author). Feel free to disagree about question (and also leave your opinion on the [meta post about this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278206)) but if you also downvote answer please post a short comment to explain your reasons. It'll be greatly appreciated, it'll improve my knowledge and it'll help future readers to better understand this topic.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti My guess is that this answer might not be found useful because it's too long, even when appreciating your commitment. There are other places to find a blog post, article or a book on the subject :) (FWIW I'm on the fence here so I didn't vote).

Comment: @BartoszKP yes also dpenner told me it's really too long and I agree. "historical introduction" should be removed but there are few links I find useful and I would incorporate them somewhere else...just lazy to do it...

Comment: Slightly off topic, but someone who uses `n̊o̅` as password passes the complexity check in my book. Length is just brute force prevention anyway, so the extra symbols do count.

Comment: Agree! Issue may come from dB column length (for example). Of course not for 2 characters but I saw 16 chars hard limit pretty often (unfortunately). Even worse when performing char buy charge validation using simple regexes like [a-z]

Comment: char8_t is not a part of C++11 and this is all unrelated to C#.

Comment: You're right char8_t has been added later, I'll correct that. It's helpful IMHO to C# programmers because the single UTF-16 `Char` is super misleading (if you refer to that paragraph)