# How to encode chinese string on android?

Tags: android, unicode

I want to encode only Chinese string to unicode string on android.

for example, it need to change `{"city" = "中国 辽宁 沈阳", name = "User1"}` to string of `{"city" = "\ue600\ue603\ue705\ue355\ue703", name = "User1"}` format on android.

please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to unicode? What will you do with your json once the text will be converted?

Comment: @Linda Fortunately (unfortunately?) Java's string length is number of code units, not _characters_. It means that `"中国 辽宁 沈阳"` doesn't necessarily have length of 8 characters (see also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27229590/1207195) for more details). Java's string are UTF-16 encoded then simply looping through each character you'll have each code unit. Format each `Char` as hex number, prepend `\u` and join everything all together.