# How to compare symbols of string with symbols of national alphabet?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

When I try to compare English symbols like this:

```
int SomeFunction(System::String^ eng) {
  if(eng[0] == 'q') { return 0; }
  else { return -1; }
}
```

all works great. But I can't do the same with `ua` or `rus` symbols. So how can I compare them?

Comment: What do you mean you "can't"? Compile error? Runtime error? No errors but the comparison always returns `false`? Can you give an example of a character that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I perform a Unicode aware character by character comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229589/how-can-i-perform-a-unicode-aware-character-by-character-comparison)

Comment: @David Yaw , yes, it always returns a false. Example is "д" or "щ"

Answer (score -1):

This works for me (the file has to be "advanced" saved as Unicode):

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    if (args[0][0] == L'Ж') { return 1; }
    return 0;
}
```